Can iTerm2 be configured to send keystrokes at random intervals for 'keepalive' functionality?
I have a serial console that times out if there is no input entered for 5 minutes, this setting is on the server side and I cannot change it.
I need to monitor the output of a long running operation that takes more than 5 minutes to complete, and I keep forgetting about the window in the background while I'm doing other stuff.
Short of writing a python script to do this for me, is there an iTerm2 setting (or plugin?) that I can use to send keystrokes at random intervals in a "keepalive" fashion when the window is idle?
